# Javascript bit shift- number wraps?

Tags: javascript, bit-shift

I am converting some Java code to Javascript to run on node.js, and I ran into something peculiar with bit shifting.

The original Java used a long and logical bit shifting, so I've replicated that in Javascript (I get the same results with an arithmetic shift):

```
var num = 3382;

num >>> 0 & 0xFF; // 54, as expected
num >>> 8 & 0xFF; // 13, as expected
num >>> 16 & 0xFF; // 0, as expected
num >>> 24 & 0xFF; // 0, as expected
num >>> 32 & 0xFF; // 54??
num >>> 40 & 0xFF; // 13??
```

I get the same results on node, FF 4 and Chrome 12.

It seems that Javascript is wrapping the bits in the integer when it runs out of bits. Javascript, AFAIK, allows up to 32-bit numbers in the background, but this shouldn't be an issue.

### Binary Representation

This is what I think is happening:

0-shift: `00000000000000000000110100110110`

8-shift: `00110110000000000000000000001101`

16-shift: `00001101001101100000000000000000`

24-shift: `00000000000011010011011000000000`

32-shift: `00000000000000000000110100110110`

### Sanity Check

I wrote a little test in C to make sure I wasn't going insane (note, there are compile warnings, but that's expected):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Bit shift tests:\n");
    printf("3382 >> 0 & 0xFF: %d\n", 3382 >> 0 & 0xFF);
    printf("3382 >> 8 & 0xFF: %d\n", 3382 >> 8 & 0xFF);
    printf("3382 >> 16 & 0xFF: %d\n", 3382 >> 16 & 0xFF);
    printf("3382 >> 24 & 0xFF: %d\n", 3382 >> 24 & 0xFF);
    printf("3382 >> 32 & 0xFF: %d\n", 3382 >> 32 & 0xFF);
    printf("3382 >> 48 & 0xFF: %d\n", 3382 >> 48 & 0xFF);
    printf("3382 >> 56 & 0xFF: %d\n", 3382 >> 56 & 0xFF);
    printf("3382 >> 64 & 0xFF: %d\n", 3382 >> 64 & 0xFF);
}
```

### Note

I only care about 32-bit numbers. The Java code used 64 bit numbers, but the numbers represent file sizes and I won't be using big files (all under 50 megs or so).

### Question

I have read the wikipedia articles about [arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) and [logical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) [bit shifts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts), but it doesn't seem that Javascript is following the rules.

**Could someone explain to me what's going on?**

Comment: Here is another place you need to go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: Good resource, but it didn't say anything that I didn't already know. It should be filling zeroes, but it's wrapping the bits around. I'll edit with a binary example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm

> 11.7.3   The Unsigned Right Shift Operator ( >>> )
>
> Performs a zero-filling bitwise right shift operation on the left
>   operand by the amount specified by the right operand.
>
> The production ShiftExpression : ShiftExpression >>>
>   AdditiveExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1 Let lref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
>
> 2 Let lval be GetValue(lref).
>
> 3 Let rref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
>
> 4 Let rval be GetValue(rref).
>
> 5 Let lnum be ToUint32(lval).
>
> 6 Let rnum be ToUint32(rval).
>
> 7 Let shiftCount be the result of masking out all but the least
>   significant 5 bits of rnum, that is, compute rnum & 0x1F.
>
> 8 Return the result of performing a zero-filling right shift of lnum
>   by shiftCount bits. Vacated bits are filled with zero. The result is
>   an unsigned 32-bit integer.

Note step 7, the shift count is truncated to 5 bits, so 32 becomes 0 and 40 becomes 8 and the values you are getting conform to the specification.

Comment: Weird... so shifting 32 bits doesn't exist? It's actually shifting 0 bits?

Comment: Yes, all Javascript bit operations are defined on only 32 bits.